# Compare between two objects and display rest of elememts in the object

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

i am having my data from API somethings like:

```
"data1": {

        "items": [
            {
                "fields": {
                    "light_voltage": "17.8",
                    "light_current": "0.40",
                    "light_power": "7",
                    "fault_info": "-"
                },

                "id": 1715
            },
            {
                "fields": {
                
                    "light_voltage": "17.1",
                    "light_current": "0.66",
                    "light_power": "11",
                    "fault_info": "-"
                },
                "id": 1716
            },
            {
                "fields": {
                
                    "light_voltage": "17.1",
                    "light_current": "0.66",
                    "light_power": "11",
                    "fault_info": "-"
                },
                "id": 1717
            }
     
     
        ],
        "total": 02
    }
```

And Another one is something likes:

```
"data2": {

        "id": 1715,
        "latitude": 2.13082,
        "longitude": 119.32131,

    }
```

Now i want to compare data1's "id" with data2's "id".
if data1's any of "id" match with data2's "id"'s
then it will displayed rest of values for data2's which are latitude and longitude.**(In JavaScript)**

Comment: So, what have you tried to achieve the wanted result?

Comment: as you can see one of data is inside in array and another one is object. so far i have done to make both in array but i am confused that am i in  a right track or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your original data, below is a simple reference for you,but I would suggest you to try it with your efforts

```js
const data1 ={"data1": {
        "items": [
            {
                "fields": {
                    "light_voltage": "17.8",
                    "light_current": "0.40",
                    "light_power": "7",
                    "fault_info": "-"
                },

                "id": 1715
            },
            {
                "fields": {
                
                    "light_voltage": "17.1",
                    "light_current": "0.66",
                    "light_power": "11",
                    "fault_info": "-"
                },
                "id": 1716
            },
            {
                "fields": {
                
                    "light_voltage": "17.1",
                    "light_current": "0.66",
                    "light_power": "11",
                    "fault_info": "-"
                },
                "id": 1717
            }
        ],
        "total":2
    }
}

const data2 ={
    "data2": {

        "id": 1715,
        "latitude": 2.13082,
        "longitude": 119.32131

    }
}

let contains = data1.data1.items.map(i => i.id).some(r => data2.data2.id==r)
if(contains){
  console.log(data2.data2.latitude)
  console.log(data2.data2.longitude)
}
```

Comment: It's Working! Thanks Boss. Really Appreciate it.